# Dont have idea how to make it look like

Tags: php, mysql

I have got these database columns:

```
user_task            | user_task_id

Drive, Get something | 2, 14
```

So `user_task` has two tasks in one row Drive and Get something. Drive id 2 and Get something is 14. How can i make array which would look like:

```
array (
   [2] => Drive,
   [14] => Get something
)
```

Help please!!!

Comment: `array_combine(explode(', ', $row['user_task_id']), explode(', ', $row['user_task']))`

Comment: I think you need to take a long hard look at your database structure more than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `array_combine` and `explode` functions.

Example

```
print_r( array_combine(explode(', ', $row['user_task_id']), explode(', ', $row['user_task'])) );
```

Comment: Also `array_merge()` is fine in here.

Comment: @McLaren this answer is not amazing. Another poster gave you the same answer in a comment 2 minutes before this  answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
$required = [];
$ids = explode(',',$row['user_task_id']);
$titles = explode(',',$row['user_task']);


foreach($ids as $index=>$id) {
   $required[$id] = $titles[$index];
}
```

Hope this helps.